# Call super for self

Tags: ruby

I have a 3rd party gem with extension for `String` class:

```
class String
  def to_url
    self.gsub /\s+/, '-'
  end
end
```

And I have my app trying to extend `String` class:

```
class String
  def to_url
    Russian.translit self
    super
  end
end
```

How do I call super (to replace spaces AND do transliteration) from my app? My code does `super`, but skips `Russian.translit self`.

Comment: This is largely a duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-im/4471202/#4471202).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! I found a way to call `super` for `self` (if there were a `super`). `self` cannot be assigned, but it's data can be replaced.

```
class String
  def to_url
    self.replace Russian.translit(self)
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no super to call. You should use alias_method

```
class String
  alias_method :old_to_url, :to_url
  def to_url
    Russian.translit(self).old_to_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `Russian.translit self` is working fine you are just not using the result.  You should be using something like `Russian.translit! self` if Russian has such a method.

Comment: Convention in Ruby is that bang methods modify the object they are called in. The string (self) is an argument, not the receiver. Furthermore, the to_url method from @ujifgc does not change the receiver, so I think doing so is a Bad Idea (TM)

Comment: @Serabe I can dig that thanks for the heads up.  Still new to Ruby myself.